# Загрузка номера телефона по клику

Tags: ajax, javascript, wordpress, база-данных, php

Приветствую. На сайте с объявлениями пытаюсь скрыть номер телефона, но чтобы он загружался по клику. Код написал, но он возвращает "0". Подскажите, пожалуйста, где я ошибся?

UPD: Ниже представлен уже полностью работающий код!

*Кусок single.php:*

```
<p class="cursor" id="phone">Показать телефон</p>
<p class="cursor" id="phone2" data-post_id="<?php echo ($post->ID); ?>"></p>
```

*style.css:*

```
.cursor {
    cursor:pointer;
    color:blue;
}
```

*functions.php:*

```
<?php
// прикрепляем js файл, который будет инициировать ajax запрос:
wp_enqueue_script('showphone', '/wp-content/themes/bakchar/ajax/showphone.js', array('jquery'));
// указываем ссылку на файл, который будет обрабатывать AJAX запрос (wp-admin/admin-ajax.php):
wp_localize_script('showphone', 'MyAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')));

add_action('wp_ajax_showphone', 'showphone');   
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_showphone', 'showphone');

function showphone() {
    global $phone;
    $id = $_POST['post_id'];
    $phone = get_post_field('ads_phone', $id, 'js');
    echo json_encode($phone);
    exit;
}
?>
```

*showphone.js:*

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('#phone').click(function (){
        var post_id = $('#phone2').attr("data-post_id")
        $.ajax({
            url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
            type:'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {action: 'showphone', post_id: post_id},               
            success: function (response){
            $('#phone2').html(response);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: @Fike, @noganno, ребята, спасибо большое наводку, все получилось. Функция не выполнялась, в том числе и потому, что id поста я не передавал. В топике напишу работающий код, надеюсь кому-нибудь из вас пригодится ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[[@kstv](/users/20225/kstv)](/users/20225/kstv), 0 - это ответ от wp-ajax файлов по умолчанию. Насколько понимаю, обязательный exit в коллбэке защищает вывод именно от этого нуля в конце.

Таким образом, ваша функция-коллбэк попросту не выполняется. Дальше размотать уже довольно просто: ошибка находится в js-скрипте, `action` надо передавать внутри параметра `data`, иначе он будет просто проигнорированным ключом настроек.

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('#phone').click(function (){
        $.ajax({
            url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
        type:'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {action: 'showphone'},
        phone: phone,                
            success: function (response){
            $('#phone2').html(response);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

p.s. насчет echo все верно сказали, функция-коллбэк должна выводить json, там должно быть что-то типа

```
echo json_encode(array('phone' => $phone)); // скорее всего, в массив можно и не оборачивать
exit;
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Не видно, чтобы передавалось id поста
2) В функции showphone() нужно не echo а return
3) Посмотреть в firebug, что передается при ajax запросе и что возврашается

Comment: Сама функция showphone() в function.php возвращает нужный номер телефона (я проверял - вставлял ее в single.php), получается, что переменная $phone должна передаваться в скрипт. Но на самом деле, получается все тот же 0, firebug показывает, что ничего не передается, а возвращается 0.